# Tesseract not converting some images

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm written python code to convert some images into string. I have the images of some mobile numbers in png format.
But i got only one converted into text but others are not converting.

Here is my code :

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import os

THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
my_file = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, 'images/3564.jpg')

def ocr_core(filename):
    """
    This function will handle the core OCR processing of images.
    """
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))  # We'll use Pillow's Image class to open the image and pytesseract to detect the string in the image
    return text


for x in range(24):

    number = ocr_core('/Users/evilslab/Documents/Websites/www.futurepoint.dev.cc/dobuyme/python/images/'+str(x)+'.png')

    print ("The number is "+number)
```

I have 24 images and i'm getting the value of the 9th image.

**This image is working :**

[image]

**This not working**

[image]

Why it happens ?

Comment: what did you get - empty string or wrong numbers or letters instead of numbers? Destribe it in question. `"not working"`  is the most useless information.

Comment: tesseract has many options to change how it works.

Comment: if I resize second image 200% then it has no problem to recognize number.

Comment: read on Tesseract Wiki: [Improving the quality of the output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

Comment: i get empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes image need some work to improve its quality.

See Tesseract Wiki: [Improving the quality of the output](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality)

In your example I had to only resize image at least 120% to get numbers.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def ocr_core(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    w, h = image.size

    #image = image.resize((int(w*1.2), int(h*1.2))) # 120%
    image = image.resize((w*2, h*2)) # 200% 

    #text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789+"')
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
    text = text.replace(' ', '')

    return text

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        number = ocr_core(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        print("number:", number)
```

---

**EDIT:** it recognizes number even without resizing when I use option `pms=7` which means `"Treat the image as a single text line."` (see [Page segmentation method](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method))

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 7')
```

Comment: When i put 200% it comes some other characters in text why ?

Comment: Module `pytesseract` (and program `tesseract`) may use different method to recognize text and it has many options which may decide how it works but it may need some work and time. Too small image is not good, too big image is also not good, blured image can also be problem, numbers too close each other also can make problem - and you may have to test different options and change image to get better result. `pytesseract` uses deep network to recognize images and it can be learn new chars but I never tried it.

Comment: Ok.
i have a doubt, i making one grabbing script to take phone images, there are lot of images. running script in command line or browser is better ?

Comment: script in command line can be run even with `cron` or other sheduler so it can ran even when we sleep. But sometimes pages use too much JavaScript and them Selenium (to control web browser) can be needed.

Comment: selenium runs in server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204294/discussion-between-virendra-singh-and-furas).